# Football player rating

Tags: regression, linear-regression

As the title says I'm looking for a math model where I can quantify and display qualitatively how did each football player performed after the game based on the data provided.

This data would incorporate things such as goals scored, dribbles, passes, tackles, saves, cards, and many more.

Research I have conducted so far seems to point at one direction. Which is OLS regression. There are some models out there but they are, obviously, not revealed completely. And besides OLS regression they seem to incorporate other models into this as well.

The one that I am looking into creating should return a number from 1 to 10 with higher being better or representing better performance with 2 decimal places as accuracy.

Although I have tried to mimic or reverse engineer previously mentioned models I have failed miserably and thus need help. What seems to be the problem is that I can't even relate data to the appropriate axis (x or y) (very big lol on me here).

So my questions here would be can this be done using only OLS regression? If not what other models should I look into? If showing me baby steps how to do it is necessary just do it, I need it. Perhaps an actual example with some random data would be great.

I have seen some YT tutorials on OLS regression but each was explained in a different way with different data and even different formulas that if left me very confused.

Hopefully someone could help me here.

Comment: This is not clear.  Regression methods can fit data to a model, but the model has to come first.  From what you write it sounds like you just want to assign some total score based on a lot of parameters, but how you do that is entirely up to you.